# Using a function with a void pointer argument

Tags: c, void-pointers

I'm a C beginner experimenting with linked lists and I found a Github repo for one. the create function is written like this:

```
Node* ListCreate(void* data) {
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if ( head != NULL) {
        head->next = NULL;
        head->data = data;
    }
    return head;
}
```

I was able to use it by changing the `void*` to `int` and then in `main` doing:

```
Node *root = ListCreate(5);
```

But then I read a little about void pointers and it seems like they can be used as generic types sort of like C++ templates, which would be useful if I could figure out how they work. I tried several things, and the closest I've got to getting it to work is no errors, but one warning:

`incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'void *'`

Am I missing a step here? I first felt like I should add something to the function definition, but I'm assuming the person who wrote it knows what they're doing and I just didn't use it properly in `main`. So is there a different way I'm supposed to pass an argument to this function?

Comment: You might use void pointers when a single function is going to handle different types of data (and particularly when it makes sense to pass pointers to those different types of data), but when it will handle a single type, you usually try to avoid that.  Note that functions like `qsort()` or `bsearch()` pass void pointers around — so if you're using those, you'll have functions that accept void pointers but convert the passed pointer to the correct (expected) type.  You can't convert from integer types to pointers without explicit casts; you can't convert from floating point types at all.

Comment: I was trying to make it so my linked list's data could be set to ints, floats, or chars. Is this a lot harder to do in C than C++?

Comment: OK; what's the data type in the list?  Are you storing `int` values, or `int *` values?  Handling `int *` is easy enough in the list code, but harder in the code using the list code — you have to have a separate `int` variable for each pointer to point at so you can store these in the list (and there's space wasted because you have both the pointer and the value it points at).  Ditto for `float`.  When you say `char`, do you mean single characters (hard) or strings (aka `char *`, relatively easy)?

Comment: Ideally I just wanted a linked list that I could use with whatever datatype I have without having to go through it and make changes whenever I want to use it. I meant `ints` and single `chars` not strings, but maybe that's too advanced for my level of experience.

Comment: Would a given list have a mixture of types, or would it hold just one type?  The issues to be solved are different.  I suggest you create a list with plain `int` values, another with plain `float` values, and maybe a third with plain `char` values.  Then think about what it would take to create a single list type to combine those three.  As I tried to intimate, for the simple types (`int`, `float`, `char`), you're probably better off with separate list types.  You can have a generic list type for pointers to structures of different types, but a given list should still be homogeneous.

Comment: Oh yes I wanted all the data to be of the same type for a given list, not mixed types. Yes I guess I'll just create a few different versions of this linked list, it's looking like creating a single one will be way over my head at the moment.

Comment: There are multiple ways to enforce homogeneity, but one is to have different list types for the different member types.  You just implement them in terms of `void *` underneath.  One issue you need to think about is 'which operations apply to your lists'.  Create list, add item to list, remove item from list, destroy list — they're easy enough, and mostly non-controversial (though you need to think about who manages the data memory to avoid leaks).  If you want to find values in the list, or print lists, or apply a function to each item in the list, you have to think harder.

Comment: It's usually easier to walk before you run. :D

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned by others in comment, it is more suitable to create different list for different types.

But if you want to use the same function definition, then use can pass the pointer to your data (`int` or `char`) and cast them as `void *`.

```
/* main: start */
int main(void)
{
    Node *list_head;  /* Points to first element in list */
    Node *node_tmp;   /* Just a temporary pointer */

    int   *pint;
    char  *pchar;

    /* create an empty list */
    list_head = NULL;

    /* Note that there is no error checking done for
     * malloc, which is not good
     */

    /* Create a node which points to int */
    pint = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pint = 10; 
    node_tmp = ListCreate((void *) pint);
    /* Add this node to list */
    list_head = add(node_tmp, list_head);

    /* Create a node which points to char */
    pchar = malloc(sizeof(char));
    *pchar = 'c';
    node_tmp = ListCreate((void *) pchar);
    /* Add this node to list */
    list_head = add(node_tmp, list_head);

    /* print total number of nodes in list */
    print_tot_nodes(list_head);
    return 0;
}
```

Code for `add` and `print_tot_nodes` ommited are for brevity.

Note, that functions like `print_tot_nodes` or `add` will have not much issues if `data` points to different data types. But if you need to implement function like `Node *smallest(Node *head)`, which returns pointer to the node having smallest element, then it may get complicated.

So, it is easier to use different list for different types. However you can `cast` the actual pointer to some datatype to `void *` if you *need* to use the same function definition as seen in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a need to wrap for numeric literals(or cast?).
Like this:

```
void *BOX_VAR;//Not require if use GCC extension
#define BOX(type, value) ((*(type *)(BOX_VAR=malloc(sizeof(type))) = value), BOX_VAR)
#define UNBOX(type, value) (*(type *)(value))

Node *list = ListCreate(BOX(int, 5));
int v = UNBOX(int, list->data);
printf("%d\n", v);
```